# Type of returning data in Salesforce SELECT

Tags: select, salesforce

Please, help me to understand which type of data is returned after SELECT?

For example, we've got such request: [SELECT Name FROM Account].

Have we got Account object or only String for Name? And if we get Account could we turn to other Account fields in addition to Name?

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one Account in your org, you can store the result of this query in Account's instance but it is recommended to store the query result in List of Account (List).

A SOQL query returns a list of records of the Object on which you're querying, in this case it's Account. To access other fields you'll have to add them to the SELECT statement.

Answer (score 0):

That query returns a list, regardless of how many records, if any, get returned.  If you specified 'Limit 1' it would return an Account object.  In either case, only the Name field would be populated.  If issued from Apex, any attempt to reference other fields on the result Account would throw an error.